# Radio toggle not working in Chrome v18 and IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a toggle that isn't playing nicely with IE9 or older version of chrome (which we are supporting). I can't put my finger on why it isn't working. This is the Jsfiddle where you can see it working properly in modern browsers. The only questionable selectors I am using is :before and :checked, but those should at least work in Chrome 18. http://jsfiddle.net/ozoeh1sp/

```
<div class="radio-group">
  <input id="opt_1" class="radio-group__option" type="radio" name="opt" checked="checked">
  <label class="radio-group__label" for="opt_1">
    Toggle 1
  </label>

  <input id="opt_2" class="radio-group__option" type="radio" name="opt">
  <label class="radio-group__label" for="opt_2">
    Toggle 2
  </label>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: IE9 does not support CSS transitions and only supports transforms with a prefix, so that is probably part of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am not worried about the transition. If you have a look in IE9, it is completely broken. Not just the transition.

Comment: Please also include the CSS in the body of your question. Don't make us go looking for it. Alos please be more specific than "not working"

Comment: Sorry, I added the link to my jsfiddle, I figured people would want to see the code there. I only included code in my body because stackoverflow made me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reconcile the differences by using [`translateX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj200287(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `translate3d`. You will also need to set [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd183522(v=vs.85).aspx) on your underlying elements. Lastly, you'll need some older vendor prefixes here and there. I've made these adjustments and it now appears to work as expected in Internet Explorer 9 and Chrome v18.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozoeh1sp/8/